# Mapping a variable having very vast range to the interval (0,1)

Tags: analysis, numerical-methods

I am trying to get a continuous mapping from (0,∞) to (0,1).  What would be a good mapping?

**Context:**
I need to rank tuples based on values of two of their attributes `a` and `b`. `a` increases very steeply and `b` much slower. To accomodate both of them in ranking, I am generating `c=a*b` and am using that for ranking. c could vary from sub-1 values to a few billions. this makes comparison very difficult.  I tried log10(c)..while that helps in reducing the range significantly, having a proper way to map the values to (0,1) would help. I am trying to look for a function to map c to (0,1) that would have a good spread over entire range of the iterval (0,1).I considered sigmoid, but then I thought since all values are psoitive, sigmoid values would be restricted to (0.5,1)..so had to drop that idea..

Comment: $x\mapsto x/(1+x)$.

Comment: The one proposed by Didier seems really good. Perhaps you could provide us with details concerning what you require of your mapping. Since you posted it under the "numerical-methods" tag, I suppose you want it to be well-conditionned and rapidly computed (here Didier's example is perfect), but perhaps there is something else ?

Comment: Yet another: $x\mapsto 1-e^{-x}$.

Comment: You could multiply the sigmoid by $2$ and subtract $1$ to normalize it to $(0,1)$.

Comment: @Didier Thanks Didier. I should have been more specific..I am looking for a function that would not only map to (0,1) but would also have a good spread over that interval. x/(1+x) does not satisfy this latter requirement.

Comment: @Brian Thanks Brian. Tried the function..it rapidly converges to 1.0 and doesnt help much in this particular case.

Comment: @Brian Subtracting 1 from twice of sigmoid didnt help

Comment: What do you call *a good spread*? Surely you noted that $x\mapsto x/(1+x)$ maps $(0,\infty)$ to $(0,1)$.

Comment: @Didier good spread : lower values (in the order of a few hundreds) mapping to lower range in (0,1) say 0.2 and we reach the close to 1 only when input value is fairly high (say in the order of a few millions)

Comment: Then $x\mapsto\log(1+x)/(1+\log(1+x))$ or even $x\mapsto\log(1+x)/(c+\log(1+x))$ for some suitable positive $c$.

Answer (score 3):

$\displaystyle f(x) = \frac{1}{x+1}$. The endpoints give it away: we'd like $ \infty$ to go to 0 or 1. Well, we can do $ \infty$ going to 0 easily by $x \to \frac{1}{x}$. But this function doesn't work near 0. Ah, we can shift it along.

Comment: Or for that matter $f(x)=\dfrac1{(x+1)^a}$ for any $a>0$.

Answer (score 2):

An obvious one would be x going to $\frac{\tan^{-1}{x}}{\pi/2} $, but you may prefer something else depending on more info you may have about the variable.

Comment: I suppose most of the sigmoidal functions ($\arctan$, $\tanh$, $\mathrm{erf}$, etc...) work nicely, with suitable normalization...